# Object is not a function Coinbase

Tags: javascript, node.js, coinbase-api

I'm new to Node.js and can someone explain to me why am I getting

> TypeError : Object is not a function

```
 var Coinbase = require('coinbase');
 coin = new Coinbase ({ APIKey: config.coinbase.APIKey, APISecret: config.coinbase.APISecret });
```

Comment: Is that *all* the code you've got? Have you imported the Coinbase code via `require` (or whatever)?

Comment: Assuming you're using the [node library](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-node) (which you should to make your life easier), [this](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-node#api-key--secret) should work: 

`var Client = require('coinbase').Client;
var client = new Client({ APIKey: config.coinbase.APIKey, APISecret: config.coinbase.APISecret });
`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Coinbase, but it seems like there is a variable named Coinbase that refers to an object, not a function. The "new" operator is only applicable to functions, and you're also trying to invoke Coinbase as a function by with the expression Coinbase(...). I would check how you've actually assigned Coinbase.